# Why didn't the parachutes on the Apollo 14 Command Module bump into each other?

Tags: moonlanding

It seems like they would need some mechanism to keep them apart, but in this photograph I don't see anything telling, unless it's those small pilot chutes that are keeping them apart?
[image: idn]

Comment: Off topic. Try Space Exploration SE but read https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3473 first.

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/why-dont-3-parachute-descent-systems-collide-and-collapse